# Possible Spring Boot or Spring Security Memory Leak

Tags: tomcat, spring-security, jetty, spring-boot

I have been running a spring boot application with spring security under a soak test and found that it gradually fills up its memory allocation.

I booted up the application with:

java -Xmx128m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:gc.log -verbose:gc -jar target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

So that I could get teh gc info out and restrict the memory to reach my OutOfMemoryError situation sooner (well half an hour, rather than two weeks)

I have run this with both tomcat and jetty as the container and then ran a bash script that fired a whole lot of cURLs at the server to simulate the sort of loads in production. I pointed jmap at the process and got the following shortly before the crash (just showing the top 40 results, and for the tomcat run)

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:        395984       32564344  [C
   2:        388697        9328728  java.lang.String
   3:         61258        5915088  [B
   4:        100297        4814256  java.util.HashMap
   5:         50892        4478496  org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession
   6:         58774        3656824  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
   7:         84773        3390920  java.util.TreeMap$Entry
   8:         51522        3339304  [Ljava.util.Hashtable$Entry;
   9:         51834        3317376  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
  10:        102111        3267552  java.util.HashMap$Node
  11:         96256        3080192  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
  12:         24101        2754560  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node;
  13:         51472        2470656  java.util.Hashtable
  14:         55102        2204080  java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
  15:         83020        1992480  java.util.ArrayList
  16:         34353        1923768  java.util.LinkedHashMap
  17:         59156        1892992  org.springframework.boot.loader.util.AsciiBytes
  18:         29574        1656144  org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntryData
  19:         18029        1586552  java.lang.reflect.Method
  20:         28391        1562080  [Ljava.lang.Object;
  21:         37178        1487120  java.lang.ref.SoftReference
  22:         47648        1446600  [I
  23:         52337        1256088  java.lang.Long
  24:         26134        1254432  java.util.TreeMap
  25:         50904        1221696  java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport
  26:         11777        1214464  java.lang.Class
  27:         23748        1139904  org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Request
  28:         35994         863856  java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
  29:         50904         814464  java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport$PropertyChangeListenerMap
  30:         50892         814272  org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade
  31:         49748         795968  java.util.HashSet
  32:         24066         770112  java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap
  33:         23748         759936  org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication
  34:         23748         759936  org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationDetails
  35:         26000         624000  javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport
  36:         12015         576664  [Ljava.lang.String;
  37:         16319         522208  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.QName
  38:         15288         489216  java.lang.ref.WeakReference
  39:         26448         423168  java.util.LinkedHashSet
  40:         26011         416176  java.util.TreeMap$KeySet
```

As you can see there are heaps of tomcat StandardSessions in operation, but also a lot of OAuth2Authentication instances (far more than the 2 or 3 I would have expected). The numbers of both of these just keep growing until the OutOfMemoryError occurs. Neither are ever collected.

I implemented a spring security configuration which is provided below

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xxx.xxxxx")
public class TokenConfig {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "touchAuth";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceServerConfiguration.class);

        @Autowired
        TouchUserDetailsService touchUserDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        TouchUserAuthenticationFilter touchUserAuthenticationFilter;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources
                    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


            //@formatter: off

            http
                    .addFilterBefore(touchUserAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .requestMatchers()
                        .antMatchers("/**/secure/**", "/basket/**", "/transactions/**", "/support-requests/**", "/devices/resources/**", "/devices/information/**", "/devices/support-request", "/retailers/resources/**", "/news-items-display/last")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated();


            //@formatter: on
        }


    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        private JdbcTokenStore jdbcTokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(jdbcTokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                    .jdbc(dataSource);

        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


        @Autowired
        private TxxxxxUserDetailsService txxxxxUserDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;


        @Bean
        public JdbcTokenStore jdbcTokenStore() {
            JdbcTokenStore jdbcTokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);

            return jdbcTokenStore;
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {

            DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

            authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(touchUserDetailsService);
            List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders = new ArrayList<>();
            authenticationProviders.add(authenticationProvider);


            ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(authenticationProviders);
            return providerManager;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .headers().disable()  // allow things to be displayed in iframes, for example.
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/images/*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/error*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/ping").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/info").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/content/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/devices/commission").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/devices/device-import").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/devices/list").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/devices/modify").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/news-items-management/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/news-items-display/*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/support-request-management/*").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the filter, also provided below

```
@Component
public class TxxxxUserAuthenticationFilter
        extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TxxxxUserAuthenticationFilter.class);

    public static final String FILTER_PROCESS_URL = "/login";

    public static final String X_STANDALONE = "X_STANDALONE";
    public static final String YES = "YES";

    protected TxxxxUserAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(FILTER_PROCESS_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        LOG.debug("attemptAuthentication invoked");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }

        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        username = username.trim();

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        Authentication authentication = this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);

        request.getSession().setAttribute("SESSION_AUTHENTICATED", authentication);

        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {


        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        SecurityContext securityContext = (SecurityContext) httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
        if (isLoginRequest(httpServletRequest)) {
            super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
            return;
        }

        // If the Authorization header is absent, the framework treats it as a non-oauth request and continues the security chain.
        if (securityContext != null && ((HttpServletRequest) req).getHeader("Authorization") == null) {
            securityContext.setAuthentication(null);
        }

        // Throw an exception if standalone device and a valid authentication is not found.
        if (requiresFormAuthentication(httpServletRequest) ) {

            Authentication authentication = (Authentication)httpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("SESSION_AUTHENTICATED");
            if(authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Access denied");
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }



    private boolean doesAuthExistsInContext(SecurityContext securityContext) {
        return securityContext != null && securityContext.getAuthentication() != null;
    }

    private boolean requiresFormAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        return  YES.equalsIgnoreCase(httpServletRequest.getHeader(X_STANDALONE));
    }

    private boolean isLoginRequest(HttpServletRequest req) {
        return FILTER_PROCESS_URL.equalsIgnoreCase(req.getRequestURI());
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManagerBean (AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what the source of the memory leak is? why do I have so many Tomcat (or Jetty) session open?

Obviously, there is limited room here, but if any further information is needed, I am happy to oblige.

thanks

Comment: What's your session timeout configured to? IIRC, Tomcat's default is 30 minutes which might explain why you managed to reach OOM after 30 minutes with 128MB. It doesn't explain what happened over the two week period, but it'd be good to eliminate session timeout from the problem.

Comment: Well this seems to be a clue to the solution. I added server.session-timeout=5 to application.properties and the problem went away. I have no idea why this is working: the behaviour indicates that if you don't put this value into application.properties the default will be infinity. Can this be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing same as we here. Take a look @ https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2084

Comment: yep, confirmed. It is a pre-spring-boot 1.2 issue of overriding the Tomcat default of 30 seconds.