# how to print java objects memory usage

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

In following question: [Possible Spring Boot or Spring Security Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162627/possible-spring-boot-or-spring-security-memory-leak)

The user prints the java objects as follows:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:        395984       32564344  [C
   2:        388697        9328728  java.lang.String
   3:         61258        5915088  [B
   4:        100297        4814256  java.util.HashMap
   5:         50892        4478496  org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession
   6:         58774        3656824  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
   7:         84773        3390920  java.util.TreeMap$Entry
   8:         51522        3339304  [Ljava.util.Hashtable$Entry;
   9:         51834        3317376  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
  10:        102111        3267552  java.util.HashMap$Node
  11:         96256        3080192  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
  12:         24101        2754560  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node;
  13:         51472        2470656  java.util.Hashtable
  14:         55102        2204080  java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
  15:         83020        1992480  java.util.ArrayList
  16:         34353        1923768  java.util.LinkedHashMap
  17:         59156        1892992  org.springframework.boot.loader.util.AsciiBytes
  18:         29574        1656144  org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntryData
  19:         18029        1586552  java.lang.reflect.Method
  20:         28391        1562080  [Ljava.lang.Object;
  21:         37178        1487120  java.lang.ref.SoftReference
  22:         47648        1446600  [I
  23:         52337        1256088  java.lang.Long
  24:         26134        1254432  java.util.TreeMap
  25:         50904        1221696  java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport
  26:         11777        1214464  java.lang.Class
  27:         23748        1139904  org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Request
  28:         35994         863856  java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
  29:         50904         814464  java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport$PropertyChangeListenerMap
  30:         50892         814272  org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade
  31:         49748         795968  java.util.HashSet
  32:         24066         770112  java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap
  33:         23748         759936  org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication
  34:         23748         759936  org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationDetails
  35:         26000         624000  javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport
  36:         12015         576664  [Ljava.lang.String;
  37:         16319         522208  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.QName
  38:         15288         489216  java.lang.ref.WeakReference
  39:         26448         423168  java.util.LinkedHashSet
  40:         26011         416176  java.util.TreeMap$KeySet
```

What command did the user use to print this info?

Btw, I have added following arguments to my java process.

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:gc.log -verbose:gc
```

I hope I have phrased the question correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the output from `jmap -histo`. Possibly `jmap -histo:live`. You run it as an external tool and supply the pid of the JVM. It is provided in the `bin` directory of your jdk installation.

It is typically safe to run in production but you should be aware of that `jmap -histo:live` triggers a full GC, which is necessary to only show the live objects. `jmap -histo` does not trigger a GC.

[jmap documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jmap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can  create a heap-dump. And then use the jmap utility to obtain a histogram from the heap dump. If you are using IBM's JDK you can use IBM's Memory Analyzer tool (MAT) to get the histogram

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/memleaks.html#gbywm
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/memoryanalyzer/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate this type of information using:

```
java -agentlib:hprof=heap=sites <Your program>
```

Refer to Oracle/SUN documentation [HPROF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html)

The exact format is slightly different than what you've presented, but the information is the same.